# How to have a List in SwiftUI able to point to multiple views based upon the row

Tags: swiftui, ios13, navigationlink, ios-navigationview

A simple way to express this would be to go back to UITableView and have a `didSelectRowAt(indexPath)` function that behaved like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) { ... } else { ... }
```

Where based upon the indexPath.row value, I can call a unique view controller (ex: the first one is a TableView and the others are CollectionViews.

Currently, based upon the two answers thus far, I can produce the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItem {
    let title: String
    let isEnabled: Bool
}

struct HomeList: View {
    let menuItems = [
        MenuItem(title: "ABC", isEnabled: true),
        MenuItem(title: "DEF", isEnabled: false),
        MenuItem(title: "GHI", isEnabled: true)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(menuItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: menuItems[index].title == "ABC" ?
                        FirstList() :
                        SecondView(menuItem: menuItems[index])) {
                        HomeRow(menuItem: menuItems[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeRow: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(verbatim: menuItem.title)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstList: View {
    var body: some View {
            List(1 ..< 5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem

    var body: some View {
        Text(menuItem.title)
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error with my NavigationLink:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'FirstList'
>   and 'SecondView'

Since my goal here is to have two different views I point to based upon the title, I'd like to find some way to make that work.

The answer posted by **superpuccio** seems to be pretty close to what I want, but with the expected complexity of the target views, I do not think it would be feasible to compose them entirely within NavigationLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a dynamic `List` I suggest you use a `ForEach` inside a `List` this way:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItem {
    let title: String
    let isEnabled: Bool
}

struct HomeList: View {
    let menuItems = [
        MenuItem(title: "ABC", isEnabled: true),
        MenuItem(title: "DEF", isEnabled: false),
        MenuItem(title: "GHI", isEnabled: true)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        let firstRowModel = menuItems[0]
        let actualModel = menuItems[1...menuItems.count-1]

        return NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: FirstList()) {
                    HomeRow(menuItem: firstRowModel)
                }
                ForEach(actualModel.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(menuItem: actualModel[index])) {
                        HomeRow(menuItem: actualModel[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeRow: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(verbatim: menuItem.title)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstList: View {
    var body: some View {
            List(1 ..< 5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem

    var body: some View {
        Text(menuItem.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code, I can get a basic concept working, but when I try to scale it up to what I will eventually need, I encounter an error. I have updated the question with enough code to hopefully convey what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CodeBender take a look at my EDIT and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would include the condition in the destination.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(1 ..< 5) { idx in
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    idx < 3 ? Text("1111") : Text("2222") ) {
                    Text("Row \(idx)")
                }

            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with a few changes I made with naming and my HomeRow initializer, as well as showing the `HomeMenuItem` struct. However, where you use `idx < 3 ? ...`, my attempt at accessing the properties of my`menuItem` struct fails and only offers `_self`.